# Can't execute command chmod 0777 * -R in CentOS 7

Tags: permissions, centos, chmod, persistent

I am trying to execute command `chmod 0777 * -R`, but the `chmod: changing permissions of ‘70-persistent-net.rules’: Operation not permitted` error appears. How to solve this problem?

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, i try to execute `sudo chmod 0777 * -R` and it work fine

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to change the rights in /etc/udev
everything there should remains to root account and the message the system provides you an insight about it.

Comment: I need to do that